# Using a facebook page as a content management system?

Tags: facebook, content-management

Greetings,

So I am making a website for a friend who wants to be able to make posts onto his facebook page, have these posts (only by him. and preferably their assorted comments) be pulled in on his website.

I haven't done any work with facebook's api before, and I'd most likely be writing this in PHP (maybe wordpress?) but I am open to other languages / frameworks depending on what is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

possibly too heavy for your requirements, but check out the (free) Community edition of the Liferay portal server and the facebook portlet in particular. I'm not saying it *is* what you want, but if it supports your requirements out of the box with no coding and a little configuration it *may* be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using Drupal with the Drupal Facebook module: http://drupal.org/project/fb It takes a lot of pain out of dealing with the fp apis, and you can quickly and easily build a site that has a Facebook application aspect to it. You can also write custom modules for Drupal Facebook to extend it into areas of the FB api that it does't utilize.